# Expo Info.plist setup for App Transport Security exception

Tags: plist, expo

I have a fetch i’m performing on a non https domain. The domain is pre-defined, so i just need to add it to the exception list in the plist, but can’t see how the plist stuff translates to JSON for Expo setup;

It's something like this to allow the non-https domains in XML

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Expo gives this to add plist config;

```
"infoPlist": {
...
}
```

Say for example i wanted to allow `http://something.com` - how would that translate to the json? I have tried several different setups, all to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

It is disabled by default.

> Right now we disable App Transport Security altogether (though this will change in the future, and we'll add a configuration for it at that point).

[This is the Expo issue Github link](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/406)